# Trouble with adding ServiceReference

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I try to add some ServiceReference in Windows 8.1 app (Windows-Store app). ServiceReference can be created, but the file Reference.cs in my Reference folder is empty. What this problem is connected with? Should I apply some special settings when I add this reference?

Answer (score 0):

**Solutions:**

Right-click on your service reference and click configure and uncheck "Reuse Types in Referenced Assemblies"

If that doesn't help, try running svcutil.exe

Comment: Reference.cs still is empty.

Comment: Do you have any warnings?

Comment: When I add the Reference it tells that Certificate is out of date, but no more other warnings.

Comment: try with svcutil.exe manually, and see if there are any error messages.

Comment: Type in the Microsoft Visual Studio Command Prompt: where svcutil.exe.

Comment: It tells that Basic connection closed. But it tells that for any references, even for working references. Maybe I use incorrect syntax. I tried to type this: SvcUtil.exe https://path/reference.svc

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51045/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-splash27)